# Error In Angular JS Setup

Tags: angularjs, npm

I am setting up the environment for my first AngularJS application.I am referring [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) link.
I get the following error:

/////////////////////////////Command/////////////////////////////////////

```
D:\FrontEnd>node --version
v6.9.1
```

//////////////////////////////Command////////////////////////////////////

```
D:\FrontEnd>npm install
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\ch
okidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"
})

D:\FrontEnd>npm start
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8

npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\FrontEnd\npm-debug.log

D:\FrontEnd>
```

Can anyone help me on this??

Comment: Edit your question , some parts are missing

Answer (score 1):

i think you miss the start tag in the package.json add this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node yourScript.js"
}
```

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start

Comment: I am cloning the project right now. It is in the process. May it be the case that this command will work only after the cloning process is completed?

Comment: yeah after cloning the project check the json file

Comment: cloned. Now I add the json  to it?? "scripts": {
    "start": "node yourScript.js"
}