# angularjs npm start shows error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I'm trying to use with angularjs with live preview with this command

> npm start

my npm version is 4.3.0

I get these errors:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393] (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\adirz\Desktop\Angularjs\Blog>npm start npm ERR! Windows_NT
>   10.0.14393 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\adirz\A
>   ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start" npm
>   ERR! node v6.9.3 npm ERR! npm  v4.3.0 npm ERR! path
>   C:\Users\adirz\Desktop\Angularjs\Blog\package.json npm ERR! code
>   ENOENT npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! syscall open
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\adirz\ Desktop\Angularjs\Blog\package.json' npm ERR! enoent
>   ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\adirz\
>   Desktop\Angularjs\Blog\package.json' npm ERR! enoent This is most
>   likely not a problem with npm itself npm ERR! enoent and is related to
>   npm not being able to find a file. npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\adirz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-02-26T1
>   2_48_04_006Z-debug.log

Comment: obvious question..are you running this in your project directory? it cant seem to find package.json

Comment: does ` 'C:\Users\adirz\ Desktop\Angularjs\Blog\package.json'` exist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start script missing error when running npm start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this error will occur if the `package.json` is missing in your directory. first write `npm init` command in your directory. it will create json file and make sure to define a "start" script inside it too before running npm start.

Comment: @sachile ranawaka, thank you. i create now package.json file but when i run 'npm start' it shows me 'missing script:start'. what to do?

Comment: add this property to your json `"scripts": { "start": "path_to _your_starting_file.js" }`

Comment: what is my starting_file.js? maybe index.html?

Comment: it is your server js file

Comment: in order to use npm start you need to create node js app call it from start property