# when run npm start, missing start

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Working on my new android app, but when i try to start the server i get.

> npm ERR! missing script: start npm ERR! A complete log of this run can
>   be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/.npm/_logs/2018-09-05T23_17_23_146Z-debug.log

I use npm version 6.1.0

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "homepage": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
```

I hope somone can help me.

Comment: Please update your node and npm with latest version. I thing it will work.

Comment: you can refer to this post : <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start>