# NPM run start: "system cannot find the path specified."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package, react-scripts

I'm unable to use the command `npm run start` . The error the console returns is:

```
> @ start C:\Users\Aristophanes
> cd packages/react-scripts && node bin/react-scripts.js start

bash: line 0: cd: packages/react-scripts: No such file or directory
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `cd packages/react-scripts && node bin/react-scripts.js start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

So if I'm correct the console is telling me there's no `packages/react-scripts` directory and no `bin/react-scripts.js` file.

I'm a bit confused. The only `packages/react-scripts` directory I can find on my computer is `C:\Users\Aristophanes\create-react-app-next\packages\react-scripts`.

And the `bin/react-scripts.js` file I have is located at `C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js`

Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this? As suggested by Mukyuu I tried running `npm start` in the directory `C:\Users\Aristophanes\create-react-app-next\packages\react-scripts`. This leads to the console error `npm ERR! missing script: start`. I have added `"start": "node server.js"` to the scripts section of my NPM `package.json` file and restarted cmd, but I still get the same missing script: start error in the console.

Comment: are you able to use npm start?

Comment: Hello, no I get the same error.

Comment: actually ..
`The only packages/react-scripts directory I can find on my computer is C:\Users\Aristophanes\create-react-app-next\packages\react-scripts`
try to go to C:\Users\Aristophanes\create-react-app-next\packages\react-scripts first then go start

Comment: Ok, I did that and now I get "npm ERR! missing script: start". So do I need to add a start script to my npm package.json? Currently there is one there called `"start:dev": "webpack-dev-server"`.

Comment: You haven't defined the start script in your `package.json` for further detail you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start

Comment: So if I add `"start:"` to `package.json` what do I assign to it after the colon?

Comment: by default it was `"start": "node server.js"` or you could define your own application script `"start": "node your-script.js"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start script missing error when running npm start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start)

Comment: Hmm, I added `"start": "node server.js"` to my `package.json` file and restarted cmd, but I still get the same `missing script: start` error in the console.