# Why won't npm start execute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I keep getting:

```
C:\AppData>npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-28T18_08_25_285Z-
```

debug.log

My package file is as follows:

```
{
"name": "first",
 "version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
 "dependencies": {
 "react": "^16.8.3",
"react-dom": "^16.8.3",
"react-scripts": "2.1.5"
   },
   "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
 "eslintConfig": {
   "extends": "react-app"
 },
 "browserslist": [
"cover 99.5%",
"not dead",
"not ie <= 11",
"not op_mini all"
   ]
 }
```

I'm new to npm, and when I first downloaded it, I was able to start it up on my local server no problem.

I wanted to switch my browser up, and in doing so, suddenly npm start is having an issue.

I know there are other questions similar, but none of them alleviate my issue.

Comment: `npm run start`?..

Comment: you need to define the start action in your package.json, check the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976870/2336650

Answer (score 1):

As @Arfeo said, just call `npm run start`.

Comment: Call `npm install` then `npm run start`.

Comment: @Ewubbs it is not possible if you run `npm run start` from within the directory where your `package.json` is located. IF ONLY this error is not about `react-scripts start`. Haha. Try executing `react-scripts start`?..

Answer (score 1):

Where is your `package.json` located?

If your answer is, for example, `c:\AppData\Eugene\react-app`
you need to change directory (only once),

```
cd c:\AppData\Eugene\react-app
```

then run your npm commands

```
npm start
npm run build
```

, etc.

Comment: it's located in my "first" npm made for me, which includes package.json, src, node_modules, etc

Comment: open a terminal in that very folder and run your npm commands