# public, src,and scripts folder not created while using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to create a new project using `create-react-app` using the command given on the docs i.e `npx create-react-app my-app` but it doesn't contain folders like `public` `src` and `script`.

Comment: Are you getting any error on running the above command?

Comment: @OsamaAftab no. `package.json` and `node_modules` are files and folder available.

Comment: Are you able to create the folders manually to check whether any permissions are causing the issue .

Comment: @User965207 yeah I can create folders.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try with these steps :

1. `npm rm -g create-react-app`
2. `npm install -g create-react-app`
3. `npx create-react-app my-app`

[Source](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088)

Comment: For more options can also go to https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088

Comment: Din't work for me. This did: `yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript`

Answer (score 12):

I tried all the suggestion stated above but none works for me. This suggestion at [8097](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8097#issuecomment-562460290) works for me. Basically, I just run `npx create-react-app@latest your-project-name`

Answer (score 6):

For those who keep trying and still doesn't work, you might have the same problem as me.

Because the global installs of `create-react-app` are no longer supported you might have it installed on your machine, thus have the old version running whenever you try to `npx create-react-app`. There are 2 very easy steps: remove `create-react-app`, then run the npx command.

It will look like this:

1. `sudo npm rm -g create-react-app` (`sudo` is needed on macs to grant you permission, it will ask for your password, type it in and hit enter)
2. `npx create-react-app my-app`

Should solve your problem there

Answer (score 3):

Still didn't got to know the issue. But i tried :-

```
npm rm -g create-react-app
npm install -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app my-app
```

This also didn't worked for me. So I uninstalled node and installed it again. It worked for me

Answer (score 3):

had the same issue on my mac.
The correct way is if you've previously installed create-react-app globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, you have to uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` in order npx to uses the latest version.

Tips: Try `npx create-react-app --info` to check if npmGlobalPackages includes create-react-app. If cra is included then try the below command `which create-react-app` and `rm -rf the outputted path`.

Last but not least, force npx to use latest:

> `npx create-react-app@latest your-project-name`

Answer (score 3):

If someone's terminal get stuck and the initialization does not completes, just open the resource monitor and resume the cmd ,

1.window+R key- type 'resmon'

2.Locate the cmd process ,right click and resume it, initialization will be complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall a globally installed package with this:
`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

Answer (score 1):

Install Npm version of

```
14.18.2
```

Install Below Link: https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.18.2/win-x64/node.exe

Comment: This is helpful

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30732091)

Answer (score 0):

It is not working for me on windows machine. It worked when I ran below commands from **git bash**:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps and that should solve your problem.

1. `sudo npm rm -g create-react-app` (Do not skip sudo if you are a macOS user).
2. `npx create-react-app my-app` (npm 5.2+ and higher)
   or 
   `npm init react-app my-app`
   or
   `yarn create react-app my-app` (if you use yarn)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this how I solved it.

**When I try to run `npm rm -g create-react-app`, it shows an error**.

So I went to the node modules directory (for Mac `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`) and delete `create-react-app` directory and reinstall `create-react-app` using `npx create-react-app my-app`.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users who are facing this issue:

1. Open **Task Manager** and check if the **Windows Command Processor** process is set to Suspended.
2. If it is set to Suspended, open **Resource Monitor** and click on the **CPU** tab.
3. From within the CPU tab, locate and right-click on **cmd.exe** and and select **Resume Process**.

Click the source link below for a more detailed explanation (including screenshots).

Source: [Github Issues](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17196#issuecomment-546640299)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using following commands

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global add create-react-app

Comment: Could you add a couple of sentences to explain your code?

Comment: follow the above steps

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i tried installing with yarn but don't downloaded all files

So I tried this

```
npm install --global yarn
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm install -g create-react-app

npx create-react-app my-app-youtube --use-npm
```

And it worked, with npm, i downloaded all template
:D

Answer (score 0):

Ok ok... If you are still not getting any solution

1. Go to other Folders of your computer(like documents, Downloads) and then Create a folder for your app and Open it with VsCode(preferable)
2. On the Terminal ( Or Powershell which is also avaliable in VsCode)

   1st Command: npm uninstall -g create-react-app

   2nd Command: npx create-react-app

Hope It Helps :)