# create-react-app is not working and public,src files are missing

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I tried a lot of solutions about the same question but none is working for me.  public,src files are missing. I have also reinstalled NodeJS but still I am fetching same problem. I ahve also tried npm install-g create-react-app but still I am facing the same problem.

When I used npx this is the output

```
D:\projects>npx create-react-app trial

Creating a new React app in D:\projects\trial.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.20.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 7 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.1.2
├─ react-dom@17.0.2
├─ react-scripts@4.0.3
└─ react@17.0.2
info All dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.1.2
├─ immer@8.0.1
├─ react-dev-utils@11.0.4
├─ react-dom@17.0.2
├─ react-scripts@4.0.3
├─ react@17.0.2
└─ scheduler@0.20.2
Done in 166.85s.
```

I tried using yarn but still I am getting the same results.

```
   D:\projects>yarn create react-app my-app
    yarn create v1.22.4
    [1/4] Resolving packages...
    [2/4] Fetching packages...
    info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
    info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
    [3/4] Linking dependencies...
    [4/4] Building fresh packages...
    
    success Installed "create-react-app@4.0.3" with binaries:
          - create-react-app
    
    Creating a new React app in D:\projects\my-app.
    
    Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
    Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
    
    yarn add v1.22.4
    [1/4] Resolving packages...
    [2/4] Fetching packages...
    info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
    info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
    info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
    info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
    [3/4] Linking dependencies...
    warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.20.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
    [4/4] Building fresh packages...
    success Saved lockfile.
    success Saved 7 new dependencies.
    info Direct dependencies
    ├─ cra-template@1.1.2
    ├─ react-dom@17.0.2
    ├─ react-scripts@4.0.3
    └─ react@17.0.2
    info All dependencies
    ├─ cra-template@1.1.2
    ├─ immer@8.0.1
    ├─ react-dev-utils@11.0.4
    ├─ react-dom@17.0.2
    ├─ react-scripts@4.0.3
    ├─ react@17.0.2
    └─ scheduler@0.20.2
    Done in 278.06s.
```

Comment: Check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59260031/public-src-and-scripts-folder-not-created-while-using-create-react-app) and check back if it helped fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, but have you moved into the folder that create-react-app created? so in your case it should be something like projects/my-app or projects/trial

Comment: yeah I did and folders(public and src) are missing in it and thus npm start is not working