# Can't create and run React Application

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm trying to run `create-react-app` but it seems it's not working the way it's supposed to. I'm trying the following command:

1. `create-react-app my-app`
2. `cd my-app`
3. `npm start`

and getting the following errors while trying to run
if you could help that'll[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gonCa.png) be great

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest version of create-react-app? What version are you using?

Comment: Try updating to latest version of create-react app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start  check this can help you ?

Comment: Hi, @JMadelaine I'm using 3.0.1

Answer (score 1):

The log you've shared says, creation is not success and you're using `create-react-app` version is very old.

Better you use `npx` which will ensure that you are using the latest version on the fly without any global installation. Try the below command

```
$ npx create-react-app festudents
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove globally `create-react-app` try this `npm remove -g create-react-app`

Then just run those commands

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: Still facing the same issue. I did use npx this time

Comment: should I run cmd as administrator I followed the updated answer & I'm afraid to answer the result is the same as before.

Comment: Yes please, run as administrator

Comment: Same issue Again :(

Comment: try this npm init react-app my-app

Comment: Its throwing err statements as follows: npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "Bhatt\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\11920" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dhairya Bhatt\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-11T07_20_38_171Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1

Comment: can you please attach the log file?, when you run npm start

Comment: here's log file link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pVl_g7HBEgHCqSjjf1hCeoYhrsbr9Nav

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the creat-react-app boilerplate,
Then create a new with the following command

```
npx create-react-app my-app 2
```