# Error while creating react app using “create-react-app my-app”

Tags: reactjs

I am using window 10. My node version is  12 and NPM version is 6but after installing they show me this message.And did not show public folder and src folder.when i start react app by using  NPM start they show me this error:

```
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Insta-Lab\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-30T09_01_08_891Z-debug.log
PS F:\my-first>
```

[image]

Comment: It seems you have issues during installation of dependencies. was project folder created? if yes and there is package.json - you can try running yarn or npm install there to see output and check for errors.

Comment: Hi, it seems like you dont have a start script.
When you use `npm start`, it's actually a shortcut command, defined in package.json
More info about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start

Comment: Hi, can you confirm that you have the start script inside the package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template [template-name]
```

Here's [a link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)!