# i had started npm succesfully but now when i try to hit npm start , i found this below mentioned error:

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-start

**npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR! A complete log of this can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-09-04T05_37_54_043Z-debug.log**

Comment: answer it this ask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start

Answer (score 0):

Check your `package.json` and make sure there is a `start` key under your `scripts`. If there isn't any then you need to make sure that there is a `server.js` file in your root folder. If none of this applies then `npm start` won't work.

Per npm docs,

> This runs an arbitrary command specified in the package’s "start"
> property of its "scripts" object. If no "start" property is specified
> on the "scripts" object, it will run node server.js.

resource:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start.html

Comment: initially when i installed the npm , it started successfully, now there are two package.json files   1) In this, it has "scripts": { "start": "react-scripts start", "build": "react-scripts build", "test": "react-scripts test", "eject": "react-scripts eject" }, –  2)  "scripts": {
    
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },  I applied the "start" in this too. But it's not working

Comment: @SumedhMahajan there should only be one. Can you share your directory structure by running `ls` inside your root directory. Also, it would be good if you can add to the question a copy of the `scripts` in your package.json file so that we can better see what you're using. Right now we don't know the type of project. you're trying to build so we are answering the question in a generic way.

Comment: ls ->my-app
d-----       04-09-2020     12:24                node_modules
d-----       28-04-2019     16:28                setup-files-react-beach-resort-master
-a----       28-04-2019     16:28           9301 App.css
-a----       28-04-2019     16:28          21879 data.js
-a----       04-09-2020     10:59           6650 package-lock.json
-a----       04-09-2020     12:26            317 package.json
-a----       20-07-2020     23:12        1895481 setup-files-react-beach-resort-master.zip

Comment: {
  "name": "json",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "data.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

Comment: {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",

Comment: ok that's the issue right there. Not sure how you are able to have two package.json files in the same directory but anyways. You only need to have the package.json `"name": "my-app"` That is the one with the scripts that contains `"start"` which is the one you want

Comment: so shall I delete those extra package.json ?

Comment: Hey there thank u so much , may be its was just a silly thing , yours was truly correct but i had done a silly mistake that is I didn't use the correct path for that in which the actual package.json exists ,Haha ,Apologise for the trouble and thanks , I owe you one :-)