# How can i fix the "npm missing script error "

Tags: node.js, github, npm

EDIT. THE ERROR WAS BECAUSE START WAS NOT A SCRIPT EVEN THUGH THE AUTHER SAID IT WAS, INSTEAD THE SCRIPT WAS CALLED SERVER SO I DID NPM RUN SERVE!
C:\Users\water\Downloads\animefly-master\animefly-master>npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\water\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-26T23_05_19_148Z-debug.log
```

I downloaded this https://github.com/ChrisMichaelPerezSantiago/animefly
and ddi npm start but got this error, im new to this, anyhelp would be helpful thanks

this is the log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.12
3 info using node@v14.16.1
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:116:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:436:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:391:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:434:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:161:5)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:281:12
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
4 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\water\Downloads\anime\animefly
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
8 verbose node v14.16.1
9 verbose npm  v6.14.12
10 error missing script: start
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Did you run `yarn` or `npm i` first?

Comment: no, I ran first npm install because the git hun told me to, should i run  yarn or npm i?

Comment: Did you run `npm install` in the same folder as you are running `npm start`?
If you have but are still unable to run, try looking at this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start

Comment: I found a fix, the person the made it did something wrong and had no with npm start. Instead he forgot to mention to do npm run serve.

Comment: @VideoGameBot `npm i` and `npm install` are same. `yarn` does the same thing as `npm i` as it defaults to `yarn install`

Answer (score -1):

Try this in sequence.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -f package-lock.json
```

Removing the corrupted files if any

```
npm i
npm run start
```

Installing all the packages from package.json and then running the script start. If it doesn't help, run

```
npm run serve
```