# Is there anyway I can fix this react-app problem? Have not been able to start the development sever

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
~ soli$ cd react-app
react-app soli$ npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/soli/.npm/_logs/2021-06-29T05_14_55_880Z-debug.log
```

Comment: run `npm run start` instead of `npm start`

Comment: Show your package.json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start script missing error when running npm start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you might not have **start** script in your react package.json file or maybe you happen to rename the server.js file with something else.

By default If there is a server.js file in the root of your package, then npm will default the start command to node server.js.

Possible ways to tackle this can be either any one of them -

1. Rename the server script file to **server.js**.
2. Add this piece of code in package.json

> ```
> "scripts": {
>     "start": "node your-script.js"
> }
> ```

Also what you can try is to run this directly-

```
node script-file-name.js
```