# npm start command: missing script: start

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm receiving this error when trying to run my node application using the npm start command on Visual Studio Code. Any help is greatly appreciate!

This is what is inside my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "bloggin-site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "express.js": "^1.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

This is the message on terminal when I run the code:

````
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/wendyb/.npm/_logs/2021-12-06T06_01_12_013Z-debug.log```

This is what the debug log says:
```0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v14.18.1
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:116:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:436:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:391:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:434:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:161:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:350:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:281:13)
5 verbose cwd /Users/wendyb/Desktop/Final
6 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
7 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
8 verbose node v14.18.1
9 verbose npm  v6.14.15
10 error missing script: start
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ] ```
````

Comment: did you do this inside project folder?

Comment: Yes, all files are under one folder

Comment: is it typo? the package.json missing the { in the biginning

Comment: where you run your command in cli ?

Comment: @HDM91 great catch! I just edited it

Comment: @AlexYu terminal on visual studio code

Comment: From the terminal where you're trying to run this, type `pwd` and make sure the directory is correct. Also try `cat package.json` and make sure the file looks how you expect it to

Comment: @Phil everything looks good with the command pwd but when I tried cat package.json, the script says {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" even though I edited it

Comment: Hey there. Just to clarify, did you [save](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_save-auto-save) your file?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just check if you have defined correct path for your server.js file if not correct it and try or maybe just in case the changes you made in package.json file and haven't saved it just save it and try again

for more help you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start)

Comment: Hey @saad shaikh, I changed the file path for my html folder and it worked!