# npm ERR! missing scripts: "start"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I can't run my project it says:

> christian@MacBook-Air-di-christian React-Fito-v1.0-01-November-2021 %
> npm start
> npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
> npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
> npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
> npm ERR!   npm run
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:..

My package.json scripts is:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start script missing error when running npm start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start)

Comment: Did you try npm install?

Comment: In the future, please provide more information about the code you are trying to execute and what you have tried / learned when attempting to resolve the issue on your own. A [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or instructions on how to reproduce the problem is very helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar Error in my code. I just was in the wrong folder. you have to enter the folder with all the packages to run the command npm start.

Answer (score 0):

> open the folder in VS code
> Inside VS terminal you can type this below code:
> cd fileName
> npm start
> file name@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start