# Trouble running package.json commands

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I am trying to run some commands I wrote in my package.json to test environment variables. However, when I try to run them in the Node.js command prompt, it throws me an error.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && node ./server/index.js",
    "prod": "set NODE_ENV=production && node ./server/index.js"
  },
}
```

And when I try to do `npm run dev` or `npm run prod`, it throws me the following:

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"
```

so, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks likeyou can a solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have this directory structure?

```
|- package.json 
|- server
     |-index.js
```

If so, try changing path to:
`"dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && node server/index.js",`