# In Visual Studio Code, for my React project I am getting error while doing "npm start"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm-start

I am getting this error while doing "npm start"

npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

I have installed the latest version, also have installed the react-scripts.
Not able to analyze the actual issue.
If someone can help, it will be really helpful.

Comment: [You need to define a start script in your package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you haven't created a start script in your package.json.
You can do it like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "[your script]"
}
```

If you are a beginner, I'll suggest you to create a react app using one of the following commands to create boilerplate code:

```
npx create-react-app .
(I'll suggest you this one!)
```

```
npm init react-app .
```

```
yarn create react-app .
```

The `.` represents the location. By selecting the dot, you are telling the computer to create a react-app template in the current directory.

Once you start to get more and more advanced, I'll suggest you to try Gatsby and Vite too, but if you're a beginner, you should stick with create-react-app.

Anyways, you can find all of the documentation here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/documentation-intro

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
But I can see start script in already included in package.json

"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },