# I'm suddenly having a problem with "npm start" in my React application. When I trigger it, this is what I receive

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm-start

```
Happy hacking!
crossdu@Kens-MacBook-Pro test-4 % npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/crossdu/visual studio code /untitled folder/pricing-card-official/test-4/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/crossdu/visual studio code /untitled folder/pricing-card-official/test-4/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/crossdu/.npm/_logs/2024-03-26T21_33_27_101Z-debug-0.log
```

I have No reason why this is not working I tried to

- Upgrade npm (sudo npm install -g npm)
- Clear the global npm cache (sudo npm cache clear)
- Clear the user npm cache (npm cache clear)

but none of them works and I am using macbook

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem here: [Start script missing error when running npm start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start)

Try this:

```
npm rm -g create-react-app
npm install -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Also, make sure your package.json file is in the proper directory.

Comment: npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/crossdu/.npm/_logs/2024-03-27T01_58_01_155Z-debug-0.log
crossdu@Kens-MacBook-Pro test-5 %  did that but Now I'm having this issuse

Comment: @KenJohn I updated my response with another solution.